How to get the max value of a row, but return the header rather than the value itself in PowerBI?
I am attempting to get the max value of a row, and use a column to write what the heading is rather than the value. I included sample data, so for instance, I would like the first row to have a last value of “Animal Date.” Sample Data
I keep getting blank outputs on error messages, so open to any suggestions.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider including the text of the sample data; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557 - (Sorry I'm not sure the answer to your question, but I thought I'd try to get you some help!)

you can get the max column name in PQ

create an index column

select the index column and unpivot other columns
 let
     Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMtI31Tc0VtIBsY31TfSNIEwjfUMQgnEs9S2UYnUQGkxgEib6hhCmIVgDhGNgCtRgphQbCwA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Color Date" = _t, #"Animal Date" = _t, #"Food Date" = _t, #"Transportation Date" = _t]),
     #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Color Date", type date}, {"Animal Date", type date}, {"Food Date", type date}, {"Transportation Date", type date}}),
     #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
     #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
     Custom1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns","Rank",each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",(x)=>x[Value]>[Value] and x[Index]=[Index]))+1),
     #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Custom1, each ([Rank] = 1)),
     #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Rank"})

 in    #"Removed Columns"




if you want to use DAX, you can try this
Column =
VAR _max =
    MAX (
        MAX ( MAX ( 'Table'[Color Date], 'Table'[Animal Date] ), 'Table'[Food Date] ),
        'Table'[Transportation Date]
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        _max = 'Table'[Color Date], "Color Date",
        _max = 'Table'[Animal Date], "Animal Date",
        _max = 'Table'[Food Date], "Food Date",
        "Tranportation Date"
    )



In powerquery, add column .. custom column .. with formula
= let a = Record.FieldValues() in Record.FieldNames(){List.PositionOf(a,List.Max(a))}
